# Redirecting query string for any search query for all URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I want to ask if it is possible to redirect

```
example.com/something?query=hell
```

to

```
example.com/something/hell
```

with the help of htaccess. I want to do it for all query i pass with `GET` method. Does anyone has any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the following rule in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /something?query=$1 [L]
```

With the rule above you can just type `example.com/foobar` into your browser to access the page at `example.com/something?query=foobar` .

Comment: what i wanted to do isn't done but your code has already done a lot of work for me. thanks for replying vrom

Answer (score 0):

To "redirect" `/something?query=hell` to `/something/hell` you would do it like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^something$ /$0/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. You need an additional *condition* that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in order to match the query string.

The `$0` backreference contains "something" from the URL-path and `%1` contains the value of the `query` URL parameter, eg. "hell", (captured in the preceding *CondPattern*).

Note that the `query` URL param must occur at the start of the query string, as in your example.

The `QSD` flag is required to discard the query string.

However, if you are later rewriting the URL back to the query string (implementing "pretty" URLs) then you will need an additional *condition* to prevent a redirect loop (to prevent the rewritten request being redirected). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^something$ /$0/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```